# Creating and Using Custom Fonts in Android Studio with only Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use a custom font in my android project. I want to do this using only Java. Many tutorials I have found use a lot of XML, which I would like to avoid.

My project uses only a single activity but spans across several screens. From what I understand, placing text in the XML will span this text across all of my screens. I do not want this. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In android, you can define your own custom fonts for the strings in your application. You just need to download the required font from the internet, and then place it in assets/fonts folder.

After putting fonts in the assets folder under fonts folder, you can access it in your java code through Typeface class.

Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font name.ttf");
for more http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm

Comment: But this uses the Textview class. Doesn't a Textview require a ID in an XML file?